# BufferStrategy.contentsLost() method for rendering

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, render

I'm creating the source code for Active Rendering using the `BufferStrategy` class.

The book I'm studying says:

> It is important to call `contentsLost()` to make sure the off-screen surface is available .

I have not understood how this method can do that, since the Oracle documentation is not clear. Also the `contentsRestored()` method is not clear to me as well.

Can someone please explain what those two methods actually do?

Comment: I'm curious, did you read the example code (under *"Here is an example of how buffer strategies can be created and used: "*) in the [`BufferStrategy` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html)? The commented code explains how the two methods are used and why they are used.

Comment: I should have undertood when a Drawer Buffer can get lost(about the contentsLost() method ) , but it's not clear the meaning of "Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
were restored" about the contentsRestored()
ps:once the show method is called , why control the contentsLost() ? The graphics object has been already displayed